# Excel cell manipulation

Tags: linux, bash

I need to format my input file in different way. An example below.

Input (excel file)

[image]

output

[image]

Could some one suggest a way?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "excel file" - do you literally mean `foo.xlsx` or do you mean a plain text CSV or TSV or similar file that could be opened by excel, e.g. `foo.csv` or `foo.tsv`? If the former you're on the wrong site (look for one about Windows tools), if the latter then [edit] your question to replace the images with plain text that we can copy/paste to test with so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to replace `,`'s with newlines in fields in the second column. You could use `mlr` for that:

```
$ cat file.csv
A,B
a,"1,2,3,4"
b,"1,3,7"
$ mlr --csv put '$B = gsub($B, ",", "\n")' file.csv
A,B
a,"1
2
3
4"
b,"1
3
7"
```

If by *Excel file*, you mean one of the proprietary spreadsheet formats from Microsoft, you could always try to convert it to csv first using csvkit's `in2csv`:

```
in2csv file.xls | mlr...
```

If the question is about how to visually reformat the tables in Microsoft Excel, then you're likely on the wrong site.

Comment: I get an error:   bash: mlr: command not found.

Comment: @Tommaso, there's quite a big clue in that error message. You'd need to install the software if it's not already installed. On Debian-based systems, you can run `apt install miller` as `root`.